# How to make a Large function work to filter by types of sample? (function LARGE + conditional)

Tags: excel, excel-formula, xlsx

I need help to find the 10 biggest values (of the x_value) when they are following two conditions (tag and year) that I define in two cells. I am working with these data in a table and I have configured the function LARGE in the following way:

```
=LARGE(IF(Table1[cont]=CONCATENATE(H$2;I$2);Table1[x_value]);ROWS(F$3;F3))
```

*I concatenated the two conditions tag and year into a column called cont which is just applying the following: =Ai&Bi (A, column for tag and B, column for year)*

The problem is that when doing this function in the different cells the output or weird numbers like 0 or others that do not correspond to the tag-year condition and most of the time, they output a `#¡NUM!` error.

I think it does not have to do with the data nor with the ROWS function that I use (since I have also just referenced an ordered column from 1 to 10, for doing the k, and still does not work). And I cannot think of another way to solve this problem.

Just a picture so as to get a general idea of the problem:

[image: Part of my Excel Sheet, Yellow the conditions that are afterwards concatenated & Green where the LARGE functions are executed for the 10 highest values]

For instance, I am searching for AFG2014 and, since I have checked the data before, the LARGE function should output 40 which corresponds to one of the very first observations that appear in my data as illustrated in the image, but the LARGE outputs 0.

Comment: Please share input data an expected output

Comment: `=TAKE(SORT(FILTER(Table1[x_value],(Table1[tag]=H2)*(Table1[year]=I2)),,-1),10)` will sort all values meeting given conditions, sorts the x_values from large to small and spills the first 10 values. Not sure if that's what you mean?

Comment: Assuming you don't have Office 365 then you can use `=AGGREGATE(14,4,(Table1[cont]=$H$2&$I$2)*Table1[x_value],G3)` in `H3` and copy it down (or `=AGGREGATE(14,4,(Table1[tag]=$H$2)*(Table1[year]=$I$2)*Table1[x_value],G3)` if you ever decide to get rid of `Table1[cont]` from your table)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use `LARGE()` in this way.

```
=LARGE(--($D$2:$D$16=$H$2&$I$2)*($E$2:$E$16),ROW(1:1))
```

`MAX()` function may work to find only maximum value.

```
=MAX(--($D$2:$D$16=$H$2&$I$2)*($E$2:$E$16))
```

You must enter the formula as array entry for non 365 version of excel. Confirm entry of formula by pressing <kbd>**CTRL+SHIFT+ENTER**</kbd>.

[image]

Comment: Just trying to understand your solution what is the purpose of `ROW(1:1)` I am not familiar with this notation. When I tested, it seems to take the entire first row and returns `1`. Thanks

Comment: `ROW(1:1)=1` for first large number. If you wish to get 2nd, 3rd .... and so on. That is reason to have `ROW(1:1)` otherwise you can just simply use `1` like `=LARGE(--($D$2:$D$16=$H$2&$I$2)*($E$2:$E$16),1)`

Comment: Although the OP's screenshot suggests that the range `E2:E16` contains only positive numbers, it might be worth pointing out that this is a *required condition* for your formulas; if any negative values were in that range, then both of your formulas could fail. In general, it's preferable to prefer `IF` statements over taking the product of conditional arrays, i.e. `=MAX(IF($D$2:$D$16=$H$2&$I$2,$E$2:$E$16))` which will work even with negative numbers, whereas `=MAX(--($D$2:$D$16=$H$2&$I$2)*($E$2:$E$16))` may not.

Comment: Thanks @Harun24hr I have seen `ROW(A1:Z1)` but not `ROW(1:1)`.

Comment: @JosWoolley but happen if all `$E$2:$E$16` are negatives? Then `MAX` should return zero, right? I guess you forgot to add the false condition: `=MAX(IF($D$2:$D$16 = $H$2&$I$2, $E$2:$E$16, 0))` of maybe I misunderstood you

Comment: @DavidLeal Not sure what you mean, sorry. You don't need a *value_if_false* clause. `MAX` ignores Booleans, though not zeroes. As such, there is inherent danger in taking the product of conditional arrays as Harun24hr did.

Comment: @JosWoolley got it, good point about `MAX` ignoring booleans so there is no need to use zero, which affects the result if all are negatives. Good to know. Thanks a lot for the clarification.